# How to install a local library using Cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am a total Haskell beginner, and am going through the Hudak book *Haskell School of Expression*. I am working on the graphics chapter, and have found an updated version of the book's graphics library: https://github.com/noughtmare/haskell-school-of-expression. However, when I run `cabal v1-build`, I get

```
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: SOE-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of SOE)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.12.0.0 (conflict: SOE => base>=4.13
&& <4.15)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: SOE, base)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: SOE, base
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring SOE-0.1.0.0...
cabal-3.6.2.0.exe: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
GLFW-b, base >=4.13 && <4.15, freetype2, old-time
```

I do know that `base` is just the Haskell Prelude, which I know I have, so I have no idea what to do here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The specific error you're seeing occurs because the version of GHC you have installed is not compatible with that package.

The reason is that the `base` package version is locked to a specific GHC version, so you cannot use newer versions of `base` with older versions of GHC. See [this wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package) for a list of the corresponding GHC version for each base version.

You could upgrade to a newer GHC version, such as 8.10.7.

An alternative is to run cabal with `--allow-older=base`.

And now I have actually updated the package to change the lower bound from 4.13 to 4.12, so it should compile fine if you pull the latest changes.

Also, I would recommend using the default `v2-build`, but that is not immediately related to the error you're seeing.

Comment: Ah, I see. The only issue is that for my project, I need a package that only works with version 8.6.5.

Comment: @Manfredian I've added another option to my answer.

Comment: @Manfredian there's a good chance that the package in question also works with newer GHC, and just hasn't had its bounds upgraded in a while. On the other hand, if a package has a lower bound, it's likely because of somethis that _is_ needed and won't work. `--allow-newer` is thus generally speaking a better bet than `--allow-older`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm the author of this package, I just picked this lower bound because GHC 8.8 was the oldest GHC I used at the time.